# Calling each anonymous function from an array of functions using a for loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, anonymous-function

I want to loop over an array of anonymous functions in php and call each one like this:

```
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($headingArray); $i++) {
            echo $headingArray[$i];
            $callBackFunction = $functionArray[$i]($file);
            echo $callBackFunction;
            echo $divider;
        }
```

The idea is that it will display the heading and then the appropriate data that is returned from each function underneath.

I am getting Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string.

Is there any way of using the for loop index $i to call each one or can you only explicitly pass the name of the function when accessing it from the array?

Comment: Can you `var_dump($functionArray[$i])` to make sure that it is indeed a function?

Comment: check http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: var_dump($functionArray["functionName"] is displaying object(Closure)#5 (1) {["parameter"]=>array(1) {["$file"]=>string(10) ""} } and var_dump($functionArray[$i] displays NULL. Is this because it doesn't recognise $i as an input?

Comment: Well if your function is `$functionArray['functionName']` but you're passing it `$i` which is `0`... why do you think it should work? Where is the `functionName` supposed to be coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$a = function($n) {
    return 'a';
};
$b = function($n) {
    return 'b';
};

$functions = [$a, $b];
foreach($functions as $func) {
    echo $func('foo'), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
a
b
```

Headings example (where the anonymous functions and headings share like keys:

```
<?php
$functions =
[
    function($n) {
        return 'a';
    },
    function($n) {
        return 'b';
    }
];
$headings =
[
    'a heading',
    'b heading'
];
foreach($functions as $k => $func) {
    echo $headings[$k], "\n", $func('foo'), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
a heading
a
b heading
b
```